# Table for plugin-list-category-post?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post, table

I'm using the list-category-post plugin - is it possible to display the list of posts in a table?

I want to have a dynamic table showing all the posts in a category, so a user can search the table and select a column to sort by.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress Answers! If the answer below worked for you, consider clicking the checkmark to mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin does allow theming. Check out the ["Other Notes" tab](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/#Template-System) in the plugin page. As far as making it sortable, your path of least resistance is to use javascript. [Here's a jQuery plugin that will do (almost) all the work for you](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Hope that helps!

Cheers~

Comment: Thank you for the response.
So I can use the template theming to show the list in a table rather than a list?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! As noted on that "Other notes" page, "You can use the included template as an example to start. It's in the plugin's template folder under the name default.php."

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've got the posts displaying in a table, do you have any tips on how to add a header row? I am completely new to php. I've copied the template code I am using below in another comment.

Comment: //'starting' tag:
$lcp_display_output .= '<table class="lcp_catlist">';


/*** Posts loop. */
foreach ($this->catlist->get_categories_posts() as $single):
    //Start a row for each post:
    $lcp_display_output .= "<tr><td>";

    //Show the title and link to the post:
    $lcp_display_output .= $this->get_post_title($single, 'td');
    
     $lcp_display_output .= "<td>";

    //Custom fields:
    $lcp_display_output .= $this->get_custom_fields($this->params['customfield_display'], $single->ID);

  $lcp_display_output .= "</td>";